# accessing properties of object stored in array in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

In my javascript code I have object variables a, b, and c, which each contain properties x, y, and z. These are each constructed in the usual manner:

```
var a = {
    x: 'foo',
    y: 'bar',
    z: 'foobar'
};
```

For purposes of my project, objects a, b, and c are stored in an array:

```
var array = [a, b, c];
```

The plan is to be able to pull a given object property from this array as necessary, but I can't make it work. I can pull an object property normally by calling for a.x, but trying to retrieve array[0] only gets me "[object Object]", while array[0].x returned undefined. I've also tried "array[0][0]", but that only returns the first character of "[object Object]".

No doubt this is basic stuff, but I'm stumped. Can someone set me straight?

EDIT: Forgot to indicate that the properties of my objects are strings. Apologies.

EDIT 2: Everyone who's been saying there's no problem with my code is correct: it does in fact work the way I've described. It seems, then, that's what's throwing things off is that, after being populated, my array is being saved in localStorage and then retrieved, then I'm trying to access it after retrieval. I need to rethink my data-saving strategy.

Comment: In principle `array[0].x` should work

Comment: We'll need a jsfiddle or snacksnippet demonstrating the issue to help here

Comment: Snacksnippet? Cool. New word coined. Freudian slip?

Comment: It sounds more like you have `var array = [ a.toString() ];` based on your symptoms.

Comment: As Satpal said, `array[0].x` is the correct way. However, it returns `undefined` because your `foo` variable is undefined. Most probably you just declared it as `var foo;` or `var foo = undefined;`

Comment: @mplungjan - more an anti-freudian slip. Ive just had lunch!

Comment: Could you show us specifically what you are doing? Give an example of the problem. [I don't see a problem with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/cg4mf3ab/). Make sure that `a` isn't JSON converted as a string. as **@Quentin** mentioned.

Comment: i think your issue is not understandable without seeing any of a, b or c object variables you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `localStorage` you just need to use `JSON.stringify()` before you store it and then `JSON.parse()` after you retrieve it.

```
// Setting an item in localStorage
localStorage.setItem("arrItem", JSON.stringify(array));
// Getting an item in localStorage
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrItem"));
// Will properly log "foo"
console.log(array[0].x);
```